# Creating a custom csrf security with Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, middleware

Actually, I am trying to add a csrf protection to my Symfony application, and what I am looking for is something similar to Laravel Csrf Middleware. That is to say, i would like to protect some specific route from csrf attack but the symfony doc doesn't explain it enough.
Oh and also, I want to use it as a hash/token for my application api to prevent from not allowed person to access to any content.

Someone could help me please or just give me some advice about what should I do ? Thanks.

Comment: You can use forms they have a [csrf](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf_in_login_form.html) token built in. Or you can use the token as a separate component

Comment: just use `form_end(your_form_variable)`
Never protect your API in such way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually generate CSRF tokens with the `security.csrf.token_manager`service:

```
$token = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken($tokenId);
```

Where `tokenId` is a specific id for a feature you want to secure. (in forms it is the form name).

Comment: So there is no way to add my csrf_token to any GET request, I know its not common but I want to use it for something inside my application

Comment: Just add the token parameter when generating your route.